# Sparkline in every row with only one arrayformula google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, sparklines

I would like to plot sparklines (barchart with the value to show in B-row and the max-value in die C-row: see [linked file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lhoFMEjG13S5XCAa1zA784yJ6FfjYJG2r31C6KUvocQ/edit?usp=sharing)) in every cell from A2 to A5 using ony one arrayformula (=ARRAYFORMULA( ...) in A2 which can plot spakrlines in every cell from A2 to A5.

Link to file: [sparkline arrayformula](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lhoFMEjG13S5XCAa1zA784yJ6FfjYJG2r31C6KUvocQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Thx for any help,

Gerd

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

SPARKLINE does not work with arrayformula. I think the best you can do is put this in A2 and drag it down past A5. It will pick up new data.

```
=iferror(SPARKLINE(B2,{"charttype","bar";"max",C2}),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm
Make a blank column A:A.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($A$1:$A),"", SPARKLINE({0,1},{"color","#ddd"})))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the MAKEARRAY function. Different from ARRAYFORMULA, MAKEARRAY works like the FOR loop. The LAMBDA formula within it works like the FOR where you can put whatever formula. The example below is an iteration of size = 10, each iteration (i) starts in 1. With the aid of the INDIRECT formula, you can reach the desired range:

```
=MAKEARRAY(10;1;lambda(i;j;sparkline(indirect("J"&(i+1));{"charttype"\"bar";"min"\0;"max"\100;"color1"\"gray"})))
```