# How to create a sparkline that copies down to all other rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HM0tI3u3ewLNS8RPTbOyzvO1yEhffJnbjeMo1meg8mQ/edit#gid=2013906764) with 2 sheets: `z` and `stockPrices`:

- In `z` I keep a list of stock tickers that I keep various metrics for. One such metric is a sparkline that shows the stockprice over the last 5 years
- The historial prices for each stock are in the `stockPrices` sheet

Below the **z** sheet with in column B the aforementioned sparkline

[image]

**stockPrices:**

[image]

To create the sparkline, I use the following formula:

```
=SPARKLINE(FILTER(INDEX(stockPrices!$B$2:$J, , C2), 
 stockPrices!$A$2:$A<>"", 
 stockPrices!$A$2:$A>=$J$5, 
 stockPrices!$A$2:$A<=$J$3), 
 {"charttype","line"; "linewidth",1; "color","#3366cc"}
)
```

This works fine, but now the formula is dragged down into each row. I would like to replace it with a formulain B2 that copies down (like arrayformula). Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Based on a similar question as yours, it seems that [ARRAYFORMULA does not work with the SPARKLINE function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037367/sparkline-in-every-row-with-only-one-arrayformula-google-sheets)

Comment: @MicTest Sparkline may (or may not) work with ARRAYFORMULA, but the answer by [Erique Bomfim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75683727/1330560) uses the more recent `MAKEARRAY, LAMBDA` formula. This **may** work except that the question doesn't include any data that a user could employ to test/develop and answer, or even to establish whether this question is a duplicate. Pr0no would you please edit the question to include sample data.

Comment: @tedinoz-- I'm linking to a google sheet in the opening post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MAP` function like this:

```cpp
=MAP(C2:C,LAMBDA(idx,IF(idx="",,SPARKLINE(FILTER(INDEX(stockPrices!B2:J,,idx),stockPrices!A2:A>=J5,stockPrices!A2:A<=J3),{"charttype","line";"linewidth",1;"color","#3366cc"}))))
```